# Laravel 4 submitting multiple checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, laravel-4, checked, unchecked

I am using the following to check if a checkbox is checked or unchecked:

My View:

```
{{ Form::hidden('unchecked[]', $product->id) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('checkbox[]', $product->id) }}
```

My Controller:

```
public function checkbox()
{
    $checkedIDs         = Input::get('checkbox');
    $uncheckedIDs       = Input::get('unchecked');

    if(is_array($uncheckedIDs))
    {
        Products::whereIn('id',$uncheckedIDs)->update(['checked' => '0']);
    }

    if(is_array($checkedIDs))
    {
        Products::whereIn('id',$checkedIDs)->update(['checked' => '1']);

    }

    return Redirect::to('index');
}
```

This is working FINE! However... I also have a few hidden fields that only appear when a checkbox is clicked. A dropdown with a range of numbers that I can choose from. Once I select a checkbox, the dropdown appears and I select a number from that dropdown and I hit submit. Using the below code, everything is saved in the database:

```
public function checkbox()
{
    $checkedIDs         = Input::get('checkbox');
    $uncheckedIDs       = Input::get('unchecked');

    $checkedNumbers         = Input::get('number');

    if(is_array($uncheckedIDs))
    {
        Products::whereIn('id',$uncheckedIDs)->update(['checked' => '0']);
    }

    if(is_array($checkedIDs))
    {
        Products::whereIn('id',$checkedIDs)->update(['checked' => '1']);
        foreach($checkedNumbers as $id => $number) Products::where('id',$id)->update(['number'=>$number]);

    }

    return Redirect::to('index');
}
```

So, this actually loops through all the number[] values that have been submitted and updates the database accordingly. So far, everything works as I want.

Now for the issue. When I open my form again, the previously saved checkboxes are checked, and their corresponding dropdowns are showing the numbers as well. Once I uncheck a checkbox and save, the number does NOT get erased, while the checkbox does get unchecked once I open the form again. What I basically need, is for the following bit of code to ONLY update the numbers from the checkboxes that are checked:

```
foreach($checkedNumbers as $id => $number) Products::where('id',$id)->update(['number'=>$number]);
```

But so far I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this. Any pointers?

Comment: How are you adding and removing the other fields ? Javascript?

Comment: Yeah once I select a checkbox, the other fields are toggled. Maybe I should look into the solution there?

Comment: probably. just hiding or toggling fields will not be enough to stop them existing in the DOM or having variables bound to them

Comment: I know that :P That is why I wanted to know a solution to check which checkboxes are unchecked, but I guess it is better to do this with javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using this to check if a checkbox was checked or not.

View:

```
{{ Form::hidden('checkbox['.$product->id.']', '0') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('checkbox['.$product->id.']', $product->id) }}
```

Controller:

```
public function checkbox()
{
    $checkboxes         = Input::get('checkbox');

    foreach ($checkboxes as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value !== '0')
        {
            Products::where('id', '=', $key) ->update(['chkupdate' => '1']);
        }
        else {
            Products::where('id', '=', $key) ->update(['chkupdate' => '0']);
        }           
    }
        return Redirect::to('index');
}
```